# Create a macro with format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM_SS in SAS Enterprise Guide

Tags: sas, format, enterprise-guide

I need to put this date in sas with a macro: `'2019-01-14 00:00:00'`

Now I have:

```
%let fecha=%SYSFUNC(PUTN(%SYSFUNC(TODAY()),E8601DT20.));
```

And the result is:

> 1960-01-01T05:59:31

But it's not right, today isn`t 1960 and I need the date without the T
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot apply a datetime format to a date value.  Dates are stored as number of days and Datetime is stored as number of seconds.

```
%let fecha=%SYSFUNC(TODAY(),yymmdd10) 00:00:00;
```

If you want to use it as a string then just add quotes.  For example you could use this statement to create a character variable in a data step from the macro variable's value.

```
datestr = "&fecha";
```

But if you require the single quotes (perhaps to generate pass thru SQL code) then it is a little harder because the macro processor normally ignores strings inside single quotes.

```
%let fecha2=%unquote(%bquote('%SYSFUNC(TODAY(),yymmdd10) 00:00:00'));
```